# When an implicit token is allowed?

Tags: tex-core

Example: the latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

% test-case 1
% Output: "b"
% Expansion is not allowed, and implicit token doesn't take effect.
\begingroup
\let\implicitToken=b
\uppercase{\implicitToken}
\endgroup

% test-case 2
% Output: "b"
% Expansion is allowed, and implicit token takes effect.
\begingroup
\let\implicitToken=b
\if \implicitToken b
b
\else
B
\fi
\endgroup

% test-case 3
% Compile error: \cq is undefined
% Expansion is not allowed, and implicit token doesn't take effect.
\begingroup
\let\implicitToken\cq
\def\implicitToken{}
\cq
\endgroup

% test-case 4
% Output: "B"
% Expansion is allowed, but implicit token doesn't take effect.
\begingroup
\let\implicitToken=b
\edef\cq{\implicitToken}
\let\implicitToken=B
\cq
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Here are my questions:

- Whether the implicit token is allowed if expansion is allowed in the context?

  This might be the only way to explain the test-case 1, 2, 3.But it can not explain test-case 4.
- If not, when it is allowed?

---

I have read the TeXByTopic but I can't find a certain conclusion.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Yes, that's the interesting thing about expansion and `\uppercase` is not expandable in itself.

Comment: in  test-case 4, you let `\implicitToken` to `b` which is not-expandable, so `\implicitToken` does not expand in an `\edef`. Then you redefine its meaning so the new meaning is used.

Comment: I hope my answer is clear but to emphasis that _implicit character tokens are not expanded_ to their meaning, they are _equal_ to the character token. The classic example is `\let\bgroup={ \let\egroup=}`.

Comment: you can achieve same as test-case 4 with `\let\implicitToken\ignorespaces` then do the `\edef` then do `\let\implicitToken\hrule` and execute `\cq` to see the rule. (if you try this test in isolation, beware there should also be something else printed on the page for the `\hrule` to show...)

Comment: there is no expansion in any of your examples except one step `\cq` to `\implicitToken`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implicit tokens are not expanded to their meaning, they *are* their meaning. So with

```
\let\tokenAlias=b
```

`\tokenAlias` *is* an `b`. That shows up in your second test: `\tokenAlias` and `b` are entirely equivalent.

However, case changing takes place based on the character code of the token concerned. (As noted in a comment, `\uppercase` is also not expandable.) Thus `\tokenAlias` is not affected by `\uppercase` as it does not have a character code at all, being a control sequence.

The only way to get implicit character tokens to 'appear naturally' is to iterate over input and use a test on the meaning of each one, replacing every implicit token by it's meaning.

---

Taking the tests one at a time (following the edit), no expansion takes place in any cases. Thus:

1. `\implicitToken` remains unchanged as it does not have a character code in the upper case table
2. `\implicitToken` *is* `b`, so comparing the two using `\if` is true: there is *no* expansion of `\implicitToken`.
3. `\cq` is never defined, and so the `\let` and `\def` lines have no effect
4. The `\edef` does nothing as `\implicitToken` is not expanded. Rather, we end up with `\cq` with replacement text `\implicitToken`: the effect this has thus depends on the meaning at point-of-use.

Note (again) that *typesetting* is not an expansion context: the result depends on the *execution* of the token.

Comment: `\uppercase` is also not expandable. So `\tokenAlias`->`l` is an expansion?

Comment: @LeslieLeigh `\tokenAlias` is _never expanded_, as it's an implicit token. I think you mean for example when it's used in a typesetting context, where `\tokenAlias` is `l`, which then produces the output `l`. That's _not_ expansion.

Comment: Hi Joseph, I have admitted your words 'implicit tokens don't expand', but why implicit tokens sometimes take effect, sometimes don't?  How do I decide it?

Comment: @LeslieLeigh  ultimately the TeXBook documents which tex primitives act on what kind of token.  although it mostly followed some kind of logic, for example `\uppercase{b}` is the token `B` but there is no token other than `\implicitToken` that `\uppercase{\implicitToken}` could be defined to be.

Comment: @LeslieLeigh They always 'take effect', it just depends on what operation is being applied. As David has said, the logic for `\uppercase` for example is purely about character code, so it's entirely logical that it doesn't affect a control sequence (implict char or otherwise).

Answer (score 3):

Let's analyze your tests one by one.

An *implicit token* (more precisely an implicit character token) is a symbolic token defined by `\let<token>=<character>`.

### Test 2

```
% test-case 2
% Output: "b"
% Expansion is enabled, and implicit token takes effect.
\begingroup
\let\implicitToken=b
\if \implicitToken b
b
\else
B
\fi
\endgroup
```

This outputs “b”, because an implicit token behaves like the character it is defined to be equal to *in the context* of `\if` or `\ifcat`.

### Test 3

```
% test-case 3
% Compile error: \cq is undefined
% Expansion is disabled, and implicit token doesn't take effect.
\begingroup
\let\implicitToken\cq
\def\implicitToken{}
\cq
\endgroup
```

This is easier: the assignment `\def\implicitToken{}` overrides the `\let`. On the other hand, `\implicitToken` is never used and `\cq` (undefined) raises an error.

### Test 4

```
% test-case 4
% Output: "B"
% Expansion is enabled, but implicit token doesn't take effect.
\begingroup
\let\implicitToken=b
\edef\cq{\implicitToken}
\let\implicitToken=B
\cq
\endgroup
```

If you add `\show\cq` after doing the `\edef` you'll see

```
> \cq=macro:
->\implicitToken .
```

and the output will contain a “B”, because of the subsequent redefinition.

**An implicit token is *not* expandable**, so the codes

```
\let\implicitToken=b
\edef\cq{\implicitToken}
```

and

```
\let\implicitToken=b
\def\cq{\implicitToken}
```

are completely equivalent. TeX will use the meaning of `\implicitToken` current at expansion of `\cq` time: in the case of your test it is “B”.

### Test 1

```
% test-case 1
% Output: "b"
% Expansion is disabled, and implicit token doesn't take effect.
\begingroup
\let\implicitToken=b
\uppercase{\implicitToken}
\endgroup
```

The primitive `\uppercase` examines its argument (without macro expansion, but it's irrelevant here) and transforms each *explicit* character token into its uppercase form (as stored in the `\uccode` vector). It *doesn't* act on implicit tokens.

### Comments

There is an asymmetry: with `\let\implicitToken=b`, the test `\if\implicitToken b` will return true. Similarly `\ifcat` will use the category code of the character current at definition time; for instance

```
\let\implicitToken=b
\catcode`b=12
\ifcat\implicitToken a%
  \message{letter}%
\else
  \message{nonletter}%
\fi
```

will print `letter` on the console, whereas `\ifcat ba` would print `nonletter`.

Why this asymmetry? Sorry, but only Donald Knuth can answer. The most prominent usage of implicit tokens is with `\bgroup` and `\egroup`, which can be used as substitutes for `{` and `}` in certain (not all) contexts. I guess that making them subject to transformations in `\uppercase` or `\lowercase` would be irksome.

### Expansion

Tokens in TeX can be expandable or unexpandable. A token of the latter kind, when found alone, is directly passed to the execution processor. What does this mean? Let's see an example. The primitive `\dimen` is not expandable. If TeX finds `\dimen2=12pt`, it will pass `\dimen` to the execution processor; the execution prompts the search in the input stream for a `<number>`, an `<optional equal>` and a suitable value (with expansion). On the contrary, in `\advance\dimen2 by 2pt`, the token `\dimen` is absorbed as the argument to `\advance` for further processing. Non active (explicit) character tokens are not expandable; an active character can be or not, depending on how it's meaning is defined.

What tokens are expandable? Easy:

1. some primitives, such as conditionals, `\string`, `\noexpand` and others;
2. *macros*, that is, tokens defined with `\def`, `\edef`, `\gdef` or `\xdef`;
3. tokens `\let` equal to an expandable token.

Since your `\implicitToken` belongs to none of the above types, it is unexpandable.