# A Question About \futurelet

Tags: tex-core

Here is something I don't understand about `\futurelet`, in this case, into macro `\xfl`.  I can successfully do the archetypal test of

```
\ifx\xfl x...
```

to test whether the next token is an `x`.  When true, this would indicate that `\xfl` replaces to an `x`.  And yet, if I do a

```
\detokenize\expandafter{\xfl}
```

I do not get an `x` as I would expect, but only an unexpandable `\xfl`.

Why is that?  Are there other tests I can perform than `\ifx` on a `\futurelet`ted token? Can't I truly capture (and save) that token?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\def\fltest{\futurelet\xfl\pdecide}
\def\pdecide{%
  \ifx\xfl x\relax[Next character is x]\else[Not x]\fi\par
  (Can't detokenize\detokenize\expandafter{\xfl})\par
}
\begin{document}
\fltest xyz
\end{document}
```

[image]

Where I would really like to end up is to be able to take the token which has been `\futurelet`ted and pass it as an argument to a `\readlist`.  But this code hangs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\def\fltest{\futurelet\xfl\pdecide}
\def\pdecide{%
  \setsepchar{x}% SEARCH FOR x IN NEXT LIST
  \readlist\mylist{\xfl}\listlen\mylist[]:
}
\begin{document}
\fltest xyz
\end{document}
```

Note: siracusa rightly notes that `\xfl` doesn't replace with `x`, it *is* `x`.  Nonetheless, there are things I can do with `x` that I cannot do with `\xfl`.  For example, I can `x to get the ascii value of `x`, but cannot do a `\xfl to get the same thing.

Comment: Note that after a `\let` or `\futurelet` the control sequence is basically the same thing as the following token, just with a different name. That's why `\ifx` yields the true branch, and that's also why you get `\xfl` back when you use it with `\expandafter`, because `\xfl` already is fully expanded.

Comment: @siracusa Yes, I see that now, but my question still stands...what can I do other than `\ifx` to probe the quantity?

Comment: This is similar to my question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474444/convert-token-to-string-in-latex3 (which is not yet answered).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\meaning\xfl` might give you more data about what it has inside.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `\let` and `\futurelet` primitives create *implicit* character tokens. Thus when does

```
\futurelet\foo\baz a
```

the token `\foo` *is* an `a`. It is *not* a macro which expands to an `a`.

One can see this by using `\show` and `\meaning`:

```
\def\baz{\edef\test{\meaning\foo}\show\foo\show\test}
\futurelet\foo\baz a
```

You can do anything with `\foo` that doesn't require an *explicit* character token. For example, if we do

```
\let\bgroup={
```

we can do

```
\hbox\bgroup <content>
```

but not

```
\def\foo\bgroup <definition>
```

One can use `\meaning` to disect the text, for example if we know it's a letter

```
\def\baz{%
  \edef\test{\meaning\foo}%
  \edef\test{\expandafter\bazaux\test\stop}%
  \show\test
}
\edef\bazaux{\def\noexpand\bazaux\detokenize{the letter }##1\noexpand\stop{##1}}
\bazaux
\futurelet\foo\baz a
```

(One could of course test first for this case.)

Comment: Is there a place I can read up a bit more on the distinctions between what one can do with implicit vs. explicit tokens?  It seems I am quite limited in what I can do with an implicit token.

Comment: To be precise, I think the terminology The TeXbook uses is “implicit character” (and “implicit character token”), rather than “implicit token”. (That is, what's implicit is that it's a character. The contrast is with having that character present explicitly, rather than categorizing tokens as implicit and explicit. AFAICT.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR You are correct: I've updated

Comment: Your answer here, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449597/when-an-implicit-token-is-allowed/449642, seems very related.

Comment: You may have interest in my answer to my own question, where I provide some code of a colleague that converts implicit letter/character tokens into macros.

Answer (score 2):

My LaTeX colleague, Christian Tellechea, as I was asking him about the limitations of *implicit* character tokens, quickly shot back a macro (using the `listofitems` package) that he calls `\implicittomacro#1` that takes an implicit token (limited to catcode 11 or 12) and turns it into a macro.

Thus, the MWE I posted at the end of my question becomes do-able with Christian's help.  In it, the macro `\fltest` uses `\futurelet` to capture the undigested next token, and then can test it against a multiplicity of match characters at once (here, both `x` and `y`).  This is cooler than a mere `\ifx` test, which can only compare against a single token at a time.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\def\implicittomacro#1{%
\def\next{\expandafter\implicittomacroi\meaning#1\implicittomacroi#1}%
     \unless\ifcat a\noexpand#1%
         \unless\ifcat.\noexpand#1%
             \def\next{\errmessage{\string#1\space is not catcode 11 or 
12}}%
         \fi
     \fi
     \next
}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\implicittomacroi\expandafter
#\expandafter1\detokenize{er} #2\implicittomacroi#3{%
\def\implicittomacroii##1\implicittomacroii{\endgroup\def#3{##1}}%
     \begingroup\endlinechar-1\everyeof{\noexpand}%
\expandafter\implicittomacroii\scantokens{#2\implicittomacroii}%
}

\def\fltest{\futurelet\xfl\pdecide}
\def\pdecide{%
  \implicittomacro\xfl%
  \setsepchar{x||y}% SEARCH FOR x or y AS THE NEXT CHARACTER
  \readlist\mylist{\xfl}%
  \ifnum\listlen\mylist[]>1\relax%
    (Following undigested token is: \mylistsep[1])%
  \else
    (Following undigested token is NEITHER x nor y)%
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\fltest xyz

\fltest yzx

\fltest zxy
\end{document}
```

[image]